Apache Cayenne, batch iterator benefits
With Apache Cayenne, what is the benefit of using the "batch iterator" compared to the classic "java.util.Iterator" ?
What is a usage scenario?
// same, but iterate in batches
try (ResultBatchIterator<Artist> it = ObjectSelect.query(Artist.class).batchIterator(context, 100)) {
  it.forEach(batch -> {
    ObjectContext editContext = runtime.newContext();
    // do something with each object in the batch
    editContext.commitChanges();
  });
}


Batch iterator provides a more straightforward API to commit after processing every N objects, instead of after every object. This generally improves performance. It is possible to achieve the same functionality with a simple iterator, just more cumbersome.

And that's exactly what isn't clear to me. In the example above, isn't "commitChanges()" called for every object change ?
To avoid too many commits I usually write code like this:
for (MyEntity entity : entities) {  entity.setField(value); } CayenneConnection.dataContext.commitChanges();

In the example above, "batch" variable is a list, not a single object.

I understand, thank you @andrus_a. Happy to be a Cayenne user for 20 years with Paghe Open (https://www.pagheopen.it)
